# Masstransit Saga: Configuring OnMissingInstance

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to configure the missing instance as mentioned [here](https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/saga/state-machine#respond) for request-response pattern. I've also followed the [sample-library project](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Library) from the Masstransit git repo.

But I think that I didn't understand the OnMissingInstance clearly. Here is my setup:

```
Event(() => PaymentAuthorization, x => 
{
    x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.AuthorizationRequestId);
    x.OnMissingInstance(m =>
    {
        return m.ExecuteAsync(x => x.RespondAsync<AuthorizationError>(new { x.CorrelationId })); 
    });
    x.InsertOnInitial = true;
    x.SetSagaFactory(ctx => new PaymentAuthorizationState
    {
        CorrelationId = ctx.Message.AuthorizationRequestId,
    });
});

   Initially(
          When(PaymentAuthorization)
          .Activity(x => x.OfType<AuthorizationRequestedActivity>())
          .ThenAsync(async context =>
          {
              context.Saga.Status = PaymentAuthorizationStatus.Waiting;
              await context.RespondAsync(new PaymentAuthorizationResult(xxxx));
          })
          .Schedule(PaymentSessionExpired, ctx => new PaymentSessionExpired(ctx.Saga.CorrelationId))
          .TransitionTo(Waiting)
          .Catch<Exception>(binder => binder
                .ThenAsync(async context =>
                {
                    await context.RespondAsync(new AuthorizationError(context.Message.AuthorizationRequestId,  "Error"));
                })
           ));
SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
```

I thought that if I send an invalid CorrelationId then OnMissingInstance will be fired and I'll get 'AuthorizationError' response. Also If I send 'PaymentAuthorization' after the saga reaches the finalize state then I'll also get 'AuthorizationError' response.

But none of them are happening.

Please note: The above is a part of my saga configuration and everything works fine except the OnMissingInstance . Is there anything I'm missing or misunderstood?

Also, Is there any Unit testing examples available for OnMissingInstance ?In advance thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you probably don't need `InsertOnInitial` or `SetSagaFactory` – those are rarely used.

Second, since you accept `PaymentAuthorization` in the `Initial` state, it will create an instance if one doesn't exist. So, there won't ever be a missing instance.

`OnMissingInstance` is meant for events that are *not* handled during `Initial`.